# ffmpeg change resolution by condition

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-processing

I want to change my video resolution with ffmpeg:

```
-s 852×480
```

How can I do it only when video width or height greater than 852×480?

I want something like this with **ffmpeg**, not with my programming language:

```
if video.width > 852:
   resize width and proportionally resize height

if video.height > 480:
   resize height and proportionally resize width

if video.width > 852 and video.height > 480:
   resize height width
```

Comment: you don't want to use any programming language? you are probably asking in the wrong place then.

Answer (score 3):

use this filter in your command:

```
-filter_complex "scale=if(gt(iw,852),852,-1)':'if(gt(ih,480),480,-1)':force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease"
```

Answer (score 1):

@LordNeckbeard gave me a link https://superuser.com/questions/566998/how-can-i-fit-a-video-to-a-certain-size-but-dont-upscale-it-with-ffmpeg/567934#567934 - but it is really messy solution.

So I just did it with python:

```
maximal_width = 852.0
maximal_height = 480.0
if width > maximal_width and height > maximal_height:
    args += ['-vf', 'scale=%s:%s' % (maximal_width, maximal_height)]
else:
    if width > maximal_width:
        coefficient = width / maximal_width
        calculated_height = height / coefficient
        args += ['-vf', 'scale=%s:%s' % (maximal_width, calculated_height)]

    if height > maximal_height:
        coefficient = height / maximal_height
        calculated_width = width / coefficient
        args += ['-vf', 'scale=%s:%s' % (calculated_width, maximal_height)]
```